# Why is iOS 13 Core Location sometimes returning locations with coordinate 0,0 in the background?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, ios13

For context I work on an app that requires `authorizedAlways` permission. Since the release of iOS 13 we have noticed that ~3-4% of our users are receiving location updates (from `didUpdateLocations`) that have a coordinate of `0,0` and a `horizontalAccuracy` of 2500. This seems to only be happening while the app is in a background state.

This is all very confusing given that the app logs all changes to authorization status (using `didChangeAuthorization`) and at no point do I see any change to a value other than `authorizedAlways`. That said, based on manual testing I've done it does seem that the app will be notified of a change to `authorizedAlways` status after a user hits the initial `requestAlwaysAuthorization` prompt with `Allow While Using App`. Then when the user backgrounds the app for a little while they are reprompted with two options, `Keep Only While Using` or `Change to Always Allow`. The app seems to only get notified of an authorization status change if the user proceeds with `Keep Only While Using` selection (and the app is notified of a change to `authorizedWhenInUse`.)

I had a hypothesis that there might be some weird state between the user being prompted for the background use (or the OS determining a prompt is required) and the user actually responding to the prompt, but my testing has pretty consistently shown that in that state the app is simply not receiving any location updates.

I've hit a wall on troubleshooting this and am hoping its just an iOS 13 bug but I've yet to hear of any other apps experiencing this issue. Would greatly appreciate any suggestions on further troubleshooting ideas or simply that your app has experienced this issue as well so I can stop banging my head on it!

Comment: I just saw what you posted as an answer. I think it's worth undeleting it as it's a good update on the situation even if it doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: yeah I deleted it as it turns out I was incorrect, this does appear to be happening outside of the provisional authorization state. Still unable to reproduce myself and still no traction with Apple and still occurring as of iOS 13.3

Comment: Ah, thanks for the update

Comment: This situation happens to me only in the newly installed device (or installation after completely deleted). After granted location permission to the app (Allow while using app or allow once), the app can get the correct location. However, once the app going to background, the system will return 0,0 for current location and location indicator is not showing:
[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho8w7.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho8w7.jpg) It will resume normal when you directly go to app location permission, select "always" and set it back to "When in use".

Comment: We also have the same problem. Do you know that you can control when the second location prompt will be shown? You can first request location authorization "When in use" and when the user accepts it you can request again with "Always" and second location prompt will be shown, did you try that?

Comment: For some reason, even it says in WWDC video and in the documentation that it is possible to incrementally request from "When In Use" to "Always" app won't show the second prompt as I suggested in the previous comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a bug. If the location is invalid it should have a negative value for `horizontalAccuracy` but this is definitely an invalid location. Run the `CLLocationCoordinate2D` through `CLLocationCoordinate2DIsValid()` or compare it to `kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid` but since you have a positive horizontal accuracy it will probably tell you (incorrectly) that it's valid.

My guess is the same as yours, that the app has been told it has "Always" permission before the user has actually granted Always from the second prompt and it's somehow receiving bad locations when in the background.

There's no notification because your app is never supposed to know when it actually has Always permission (presumably to prevent it from waiting until it has Always to start abusing background location).

Either file a bug with Apple or use a DTS incident. If it's a framework bug you should be re-credited your DTS and get faster support at the same time.

In the meantime, add extra checks for invalid locations that include the coordinate being `0,0`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! We're discarding these location reports for the time being but its quite frustrating as we know that we're losing location data (which our app uses to generate walk paths for our users) and its unclear where the blame lays. I've already filed a bug with Apple (fwiw) but hadn't thought to reach out to DTS, will definitely try that route.

Comment: Other answers on SO have mentioned turning on `showsBackgroundLocationIndicator` to continue getting locations in the background. I've found that manually toggling the permission in the settings will immediately change the permission, so you could direct your users to do that too.

Comment: Just out of interest, are your users receiving a `0,0` location mixed in with a bunch of valid locations, or are they just receiving a stream of `0,0` locations? Is their background session lasting longer than 10 or 15 seconds?

Comment: It does appear that this is occurring right as the `In Use` state is ending, its consistently ~10 seconds after the app enters the background that this happens. I'm in touch with DTS and they're in agreement that this sounds related to the provisional authorization state. The issue for me is that all the docs and the WWDC video on Core Location iOS 13 claim that location updates will be withheld during this state until the provisional status is resolved. Given that understanding, this is unexpected behavior, I've asked that they either update docs accordingly or fix this behavior.

Comment: I have a question to 1 billion dollars,
I have already check all the new condition of use of CoreLocation and something wrong with my process Authorization CoreLocation...
I have followed every steps to validate the new Authorization CoreLocation process to be in case Always Authorization and unfortunately even if my GPS is On in Background, i don't get position any more ...
Or if I get a position it's a bad Location like (lat: 0, Lon: 0, accuracy: 2500).
In iOS 12 everything working like a charm. iOS 13 new rules block app anything to help me ?

Comment: @GuillaumeBlanchet welcome to the party :) I've yet to find a solution/cause for this and Apple has been unhelpful in resolving or working around the issue though I still hold out hope for an OS update that will resolve it. I tested a workaround that would restart the location manager after it reported this bad location but it only seems to help a small percentage of the time.

Comment: I do have the same Issue. Is there already a DTS number that I could refer to when opening up another DTS request.

Comment: We have struggled with the same issue, receiving 0,0 position and accuracy 2500. But only on some phones, even though all of them had iOS 13.6.1 installed. Entered settings, and the app had "Always" permission for location. Then Apple released 13.7 two days ago. After updating the units that had trouble with 0,0/2500 got a permission request to keep "Always" immediately after iOS upgrade. Then none of our devices has this issue anymore. Looks like an iOS bug.